# Test failing No value at JSON path

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I hope someone can help me with this issue.
I have searched for issues related to JsonPath and made changes accordingly but I am not getting anywhere.

The error I get is:
**java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.echo"**

In the console I see this

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

The code in question can be found here(original code)
https://github.com/rohit-neeshu/UBS_Sample_test/blob/master/src/test/java/com/hackerrank/sample/SampleApplicationTests.java

I have made changes by implementing the service but that didn't help
Here's what I did so far:

```
package com.hackerrank.sample;

import com.hackerrank.sample.dto.StringResponse;
import com.hackerrank.sample.service.HelloService;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class SampleApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    HelloService helloService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

    }

    @Test
    public void defaultHelloTest() throws Exception {
        when(helloService.getDefaultHello()).thenReturn(new StringResponse("Hello World!"));
        mockMvc.perform(get("/defaultHello"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.echo").value("Hello World!"))
                .andExpect(
                        status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package com.hackerrank.sample.controller;

import com.hackerrank.sample.dto.StringResponse;
import com.hackerrank.sample.service.HelloService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class SampleController {

    HelloService helloService;

    public SampleController(HelloService service) {
        this.helloService = service;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = {"/defaultHello/{message}"})
    public StringResponse getDefaultHello(@PathVariable String message) {
        return helloService.getDefaultHello(message);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = {"/defaultHello"})
    public StringResponse getDefaultHello() {
        return helloService.getDefaultHello();
    }

}
```

Service

```
    package com.hackerrank.sample.service;

import com.hackerrank.sample.dto.StringResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Repository
public interface HelloService {
    public StringResponse getDefaultHello();
    public StringResponse getDefaultHello(String message);
}
```

Service Implementation

```
package com.hackerrank.sample.service;

import com.hackerrank.sample.dto.StringResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService {

    private StringResponse stringResponse;


    public HelloServiceImpl(StringResponse stringResponse) {
        this.stringResponse = stringResponse;
    }

    @Override
    public StringResponse getDefaultHello() {
        return new StringResponse("Hello World!");
    }

    @Override
    public StringResponse getDefaultHello(String message) {
        return new StringResponse("Hello + " + message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Like the error says, you are passing a string "$.echo" to jsonPath.  I don't know your test framework, but it looks like you want $.echo to return a path for jsonPath - which won't work as you have it. It likely needs to be run by a system command or passed into another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "value()" cannot be used to evaluate JSON . To evaluate JSON structure, we can use `is()`.

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.echo", is("Hello World!"))
```